# Return String from Unknown Class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object

Say I have 2 classes:

Class 1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string Test = "Class1";
}
```

And Class 2:

```
public class Class2
{
    public static string Test = "Class2";
}
```

Now in my mainform, I have an array of objects:

```
object[] Objects = new object[2];
Objects[0] = new Class1();
Objects[1] = new Class2();
```

Now say I would want to get the `Test` string from `object[0]`
How would I retrieve that?

I have tried

```
Objects[0].GetType().GetProperty("Test");  //Returns a NullReference
```

Comment: Cast it to `Class1` or use inheritance and polymorphism. Let both classes inherit the same base class or implement the same interface which has a property `Test`. Then create an array of this class/interface and you can access this property without casting.

Comment: `Class1.Test` and `Class2.Test`? They are static properties, you dont need object to access them. You can access them directly with the class names.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The `Test` are `static`, so no inheritance/polymorphism...

Comment: @xanatos: true and they are fields. But this is just an example. Maybe they're accidentially static. I just wanted to give OP another way of looking at things. Reflection should be the very last resort and is much too often abused to solve an issue which should not exist if you've understood the concepts of OOP. Also, using `Object` as type should not be needed often nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you cannot call anything declared static on a instance. And secondly this is exactly what polymorphism is for.

```
public interface IClass
{
    string Test { get; }
}

public class Class1 : IClass
{
    public string Test
    {
        get { return "Class1"; }
    }
}

public class Class2 : IClass
{
    public string Test
    {
        get { return "Class2"; }
    }
}


IClass[] Objects = new IClass[2];
Objects[0] = new Class1();
Objects[1] = new Class2();
```

Then you can just do.

```
var str = Objects[0].Test;
```

Comment: Either that (base class) or an use an interface, depending on how your two objects are related.

Comment: Agree, in this given scenario an interface would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
if (object[0] is Class1) { ... }
if (object[1] is Class2) { ... }
```

such as

```
Console.WriteLine(Class1.Test );
```

So you could do `if (Objects[0] is Class1) Console.WriteLine(Class1.Text);` as a whole piece of code.

Comment: No. It cannot access static field `Test` in non-static context. Because `Test` is static in non-static class!

Comment: Corrected for clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
Objects[0].GetType().GetField("Test").GetValue(null);
```